# Set proxy exclusion android emulator

Tags: ionic-framework, proxy, android-emulator

I'm using Ionic 3 and and android emulator to develop an app. I am behind a corporate proxy. My app needs both access to the outside and to my development machine. I've configured the emulated android's APN to use the corporate proxy, but is is there anyway to specify that this proxy should not be used for my development machine?

I've found some old posts advising to install a local proxy on my development machine, and direct all the traffic to that proxy so that it can be dispatched to the outside or my dev PC.  But I was looking for a simpler way, i.e. proxy exclusions.

Thanks

Comment: did you try environmental config file for managing proxies seperately for Dev and Prod release? Its not officially release but work around here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/762

Comment: I did find that link (wile looking at something else) but but my question is not really about environments here. The proxy needs to be set on the device itself

Answer (score 0):

You bypass corporate proxy from your machine. If you use **Ubuntu** [*There should be similar setting for other OS*], you can get the proxy setting in **System > Network > Network Proxy.** If your PC is using Your corporate proxy, you can remove that and click "Apply System Wide". Or if you did set up your own proxy, then you can use that proxy. Here is the snapshot.

[image]

Or You can provide proxy bypassing javascript in the setting.

Here is the link for proxy bypassing javascript.

http://cavaliercoder.com/blog/proxy-auto-configuration-script-to-bypass-proxy-for-local-addresses.html